# react-native-reanimated:androidJavadoc errors running react-native app on android devices

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, react-native-reanimated

I'm not sure what I've changed, but I can no longer get my app running on android devices. Running `npx react-native run-android --deviceId abcdefg123` results in the following errors:

```
info Done writing bundle output
info Done writing sourcemap output
info Copying 47 asset files
info Done copying assets

> Task :react-native-reanimated:androidJavadoc FAILED
/Users/[....]/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/reanimated/NodesManager.java:5: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
                                ^
/Users/[....]/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/reanimated/NodesManager.java:6: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback;
                                ^
/Users/[....]/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/reanimated/NodesManager.java:7: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.GuardedRunnable;
                                ^
/Users/[....]/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/reanimated/NodesManager.java:8: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JSApplicationIllegalArgumentException;
```

...plus loads more similar errors, then...

```
100 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:androidJavadoc'.
> Javadoc generation failed. Generated Javadoc options file (useful for troubleshooting): '/Users/[....]/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/build/tmp/androidJavadoc/javadoc.options'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1m 33s
2342 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 2336 up-to-date
error Failed to build the app. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew build -x lint
    at makeError (/Users/[....]/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I've been going in circles for a day now, trying to figure it out but I keep coming back to this error. Any ideas what I've done wrong, or what to try next?

---

**Update:**

If I remove the `--deviceId` flag, the app will run on the android emulator just fine. And it also works if I plug in a Samsung device I have.

When I plug in another device (Mi Max 2), I'm now getting a different error - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64787260/1918059)

However, the `react-native-reanimated:androidJavadoc` error described above still persists for both devices when I attempt to target either of them directly with the `deviceId` flag.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? I am having the same issue, its annoying me lol.

Comment: Nope sorry, I couldn't get it working on the Mi Max device. No problems on the Samsung, but I can't target it directly with --deviceId (I just run-android and accept that the emulator is going to start up as well!)

Comment: I am also stuck on the same issue.

./node_modules/.bin/react-native run-android --port=8002 --no-packager --deviceId=XXXXXXXX --variant=debug fails.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue, by following the installation guide of React-native-reanimated.
First install :

> yarn add react-native-reanimated@next

- Turn on Hermes engine by editing android/app/build.gradle :

> project.ext.react = [
> enableHermes: true  // <- here | clean and rebuild if changing
> ]

- Plug Reanimated in MainApplication.java

> import com.facebook.react.bridge.JSIModulePackage; // <- add
> import com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedJSIModulePackage; // <- add
> ...
> private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
> ...
>
> ```
>  @Override
>  protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
>    return "index";
>  }
>
>  @Override
>  protected JSIModulePackage getJSIModulePackage() {
>    return new ReanimatedJSIModulePackage(); // <- add
>  }
> ```
>
> };
> ...

- Then clean your project and Build using ./gradlew clean and ./gradlew build in android folder of your project.

https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/installation