# SecurityException during app:installDebug Task while attempting to run react-native app on MI MAX 2 android device

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

Running `npx react-native run-android` is working on the android emulator, and also on a Samsung device I have. But when connecting a MI MAX 2 device, I get the following:

```
> Task :app:installDebug
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'MI MAX 2 - 7.1.1' for app:debug

> Task :app:installDebug FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
847 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 845 up-to-date
Unable to install /Users/[....]/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Unknown failure: Error: java.lang.SecurityException: You need the android.permission.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS permission to use the PackageManager.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS flag
        at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceImpl.installRemotePackage(DeviceImpl.java:1224)
        at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceImpl.installPackage(DeviceImpl.java:1050)
        at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceImpl.installPackage(DeviceImpl.java:1026)
        at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceImpl.installPackage(DeviceImpl.java:1015)
        at ... etc, etc, etc

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Unknown failure: Error: java.lang.SecurityException: You need the android.permission.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS permission to use the PackageManager.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS flag

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 30s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=4105
Unable to install /Users/[....]/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
```

Note: I tried adding the following to my `AndroidManifest.xml` but it didn't appear to make a difference:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS"/>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you share you AndroidManifest file > permissions section ?

Comment: Hi @HendEl-Sahli - I updated my question, re: AndroidManifest permissions

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Ensure that all three

1. Developer Options -> USB debugging
2. Developer Options -> USB debugging (Security settings)
3. Developer Options -> Install via USB

are turned on

Comment: OMG, why even there are two USB debugging

Comment: make sure "install via usb " is turned on  in developer options

Comment: if the above steps didn't work, try restarting the device or selecting the correct "Use of USB" option. I have a Redmi device so I had to select the "No data transfer" option.

Answer (score 38):

I could fix it on a MI POCO F2 Pro enabling `Developer Options` -> `USB debugging (Security settings)` option.

Comment: I do already have USB debugging enabled on both devices. Still no love unfortunately

Comment: @DanielLoiterton have you enabled two options (`USB debugging` and `USB debugging (Security settings)`)?

Answer (score 12):

On my Xiaomi Redmi Note 7, I had to turn on another option which is called "USB Debugging (Security Settings)".

It's located not far below the "USB Debugging" option.

Comment: @thanks dude works like a charm over Xiaomi Redmi 7a

Answer (score 4):

Enable the USB debugging (Security settings) from developer option. It will ask you to insert SIM card if the phone doesn't have a SIM inserted.

Comment: Personally I don't like this sim card thing :(

Answer (score 1):

The problem came for me after I removed the `SIM card` from my MI device.
I can't accept the USB debugging (Security settings) anymore since that..

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I have tried this , I had my Sim inserted and Developer Options -> USB debugging (Security settings) and USB Debugging- Both Turned ON but in my device i was still facing the same issue then i activated : Install Via USB - Turned ON. Now Its working fine i guess my REDMI device had this additional option other phone might not have.

This webpage has all related capabilities for running Appium :
http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/index.html
In my capabilities section i also added 2 new capabilities for Actual device and imported a library saying:

```
import io.appium.java_client.android.appmanagement.*;
    DesiredCapabilities cap= new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", "true");
    cap.setCapability("enforceAppInstall", "true");
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28980697)

Comment: This is the solution i provided , the way i solved the issue

Comment: Install via USB is available in all Redmi devices and is required for any app install along with normal USB debugging. You need Security settings only when you need to imitate gestures, change settings, and grant permissions via USB.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Developer Options -> USB debugging (Security settings) is enabled

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).