# How to solve the problem of installing the apk through adb and getting all the permissions

Tags: java, android

I want to install an apk through adb to enable all permissions for me, but I have the error below.

[image]

i set INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS in manifest
but it does not work and I have the same error again
where is the problem from? thank you

My Manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Does an answer to this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64787260/securityexception-during-appinstalldebug-task-while-attempting-to-run-react-nat

Comment: Then ... please ... do yourself a favor, and next time first search for your topic or your problem. It might already have been asked and answered.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Sure bro, i wish you all the best, thanks